# Responsive image not filling DIV when shrinking viewport

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, responsive

I have a 2 column layout in which one column contains an image and the other column contains space for text, buttons etc.

**Problem**

The problem that I am having is with the image column specifically. When the image column is scaled at larger viewports, it works great and scales exactly as planned. Both the columns adjust at the same height and all items scale properly. However, as the window gets smaller, the image keeps getting smaller as well. The two columns are no longer even and the background of the image column begins to show. I think this is happening because the image is trying to keep the same aspect ratio.

**Intention**

The intention is that as the viewport scales down, The respective columns also scale down while keeping their same width ratio and the height of the two columns should always match.

**Tried / Failed Solutions**

- `height: 100%` on the `img` attribute - this results in the columns not scaling properly.
- Using the `picture` element instead of the `img` tag
- using `object-fit` of cover and fill on the image.

Here is a code snippet and a JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/CztS6/37/

```css
.flex-container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
}
.full-width-four {
    width: calc(33.3333333333%);
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    background: #dbdfe5;
    flex: 1;
}
.recruitment{
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  
}
.full-width-eight{
    width: calc(66.6666666667%);
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    background: #b4bac0;
    flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="full-width-four">
    <img class="recruitment" src="http://via.placeholder.com/570x415"> 
  </div>
  <div class="full-width-eight">Column 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please try `.recruitment{height: 100%;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, Is this what your are looking for?

I commented `min-height: 300px;` for `flex-container`

I also added `width:100%;` to the image

```css
.flex-container {
    width: 100%;
    /* min-height: 300px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
}
.full-width-four {
    width: calc(33.3333333333%);
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    background: #dbdfe5;
    flex: 1;
}
.recruitment{
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  width:100%;
  
}
.full-width-eight{
    width: calc(66.6666666667%);
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    background: #b4bac0;
    flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="full-width-four">
    <img class="recruitment" src="http://via.placeholder.com/570x415"> 
  </div>
  <div class="full-width-eight">Column 2</div>
</div>
```